# Can I activate the Trackmania 2 Steam Key on Maniaplanet?

Tags: steam, trackmania-2

Is it possible to activate the Key on Maniaplanet if I bought Trackmania 2 on Steam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out, that you can't activate it directly on [maniaplanet.com](http://www.maniaplanet.com/), but if you got the key like Jorris explained it, follow these steps:

- start the game
- click on profile
- click on the button named **"Enter Key"**
- paste your key here

After that the game is registered on your maniaplanet.com account and you can install it without steam.

Answer (score 4):

Some games allow you to do this, most don't.
The game "Prison Architect" for example does support this:

[image]

Theres however a second way to obtain your key, by looking for it in your Windows Registry.

Open regedit.exe (enter **regedit** in the "Run" window after pressing <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) and browse to:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam\
```

In there you will find folders called `TestApp228760` (TrackMania 2 Canyon) and/or `TestApp232910` (TrackMania 2 Storm). Inside those folders there will be an object named `SteamKey` containing your key.

[image]

Comment: Seems the regular way became available in the meanwhile for Trackmania²